# Why does D3's brush start event interfere with later brush events?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

In the minimal example below, the brush is used to select circles (assigning them the `selected` class) and then emptied at the end. Without the `start` event, the selection augments with each brush action as expected. The `brushstart()` function is added, however, to clear at the start of each brush action unless the ctrl key is pressed. Somehow, it ends up wiping out the selection that takes place later during the `brush` event as well. You can see the circles get selected with the change of color during brushing, but when the mouse is released, they all become deselected.

How can I fix this? What really puzzles me is how `brushstart()` can cancel the selections made by `brushmove()`.

```js
'use strict'
var random = d3.randomUniform(0.1, 0.9),
  points = d3.range(50).map(function() {
    return [random(), random()]
  });

var svg = d3.select("svg"),
  width = +svg.attr("width"),
  height = +svg.attr("height");

var x = d3.scaleLinear()
  .domain([0, 1])
  .range([0, width]),
  y = d3.scaleLinear()
  .domain([0, 1])
  .range([height, 0]);

var brush = d3.brush()
  .on('start', brushstart)
  .on('brush', brushmove)
  .on("end", brushended);

var circles = svg.selectAll("circle")
  .data(points)
  .enter().append("circle")
  .attr("cx", function(d) {
    return x(d[0]);
  })
  .attr("cy", function(d) {
    return y(d[1]);
  })
  .attr("r", 2.5)
  .attr("fill", 'steelblue');

svg.append("g")
  .attr("class", "brush")
  .call(brush);

function brushstart() {
  // works as expected w/o the following line
  if (!d3.event.ctrlKey) {
    circles.classed('selected', false)
  }
}

function brushmove() {
  var s = d3.event.selection;
  if (s) {
    var newlySelected = circles.filter(function(d) {
      return s[0][0] <= x(d[0]) && x(d[0]) <= s[1][0] &&
        s[0][1] <= y(d[1]) && y(d[1]) <= s[1][1];
    });
    newlySelected.classed('selected', true);
  }
}

function brushended() {
  var s = d3.event.selection;
  if (s) {
    svg.select(".brush").call(brush.move, null);
  }
}
```

```css
.selected {
  fill: crimson
}
```

```html
<svg width="300" height="300"></svg>
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

brushstart is called from brushend:

```
if (s) {
    svg.select(".brush").call(brush.move, null);
  }
```

Maybe you could check the selection in brushstart:

```
function brushstart() {
  // works as expected w/o the following line
  if (!d3.event.ctrlKey && d3.event.selection) {
    circles.classed('selected', false)
  }
}
```

Comment: Many thanks. Your suggestion solves the stated problem, but the key check  also needs to be changed to `!d3.event.sourceEvent.ctrlKey` for this to work as intended. The latter was my mistake.